# Pass table-type object as input parameter to Stored Procedure in Oracle from C#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have stored procedure which accepts table-type as input parameter.
How to pass object from c# code?

```
create or replace TYPE CUSTOM_TYPE AS OBJECT 
( 
  attribute1 VARCHAR(10),
  attribute2 VARCHAR(10)
);

create or replace TYPE CUSTOM_TYPE_ARRAY AS TABLE OF CUSTOM_TYPE;

PROCEDURE SP_TEST
(
  P_TABLE_IN IN CUSTOM_TYPE_ARRAY,
  P_RESULT_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
) AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN P_RESULT_OUT FOR
    SELECT  ti.attribute1, ti.attribute2, ti.attribute3
    FROM  TABLE(P_TABLE_IN) ea inner join MYTABLE ti on ea.attribute1 = ti.attribute1 and ea.attribute2 = ti.attribute2;
END SP_TEST;
```

And trying to add parameter like this:

```
var oracleParam = new OracleParameter();
oracleParam.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Array;
oracleParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
oracleParam.ParameterName = "P_TABLE_IN";
oracleParam.Value = entities;
oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(oracleParam);
```

Where entities is an instance of custom collection of entities (with defined oracle attributes mapping)

```
public class EntityUdt
{
    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("attribute1")]
    public string attribute1 {get;set;}
    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("attribute2")]
    public string attribute2 {get;set;}
}
```

I followed [this guide](http://appsjack.blogspot.co.uk/2010/09/pass-custom-udt-types-to-oracle-stored.html) to define .net entity properly but still no luck with passing my list:

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233079
>   Message='EntityUdt::attribute1::OracleObjectMappingAttribute'
>   cannot be set to an invalid value of 'attribute1'
>   Source=Oracle.DataAccess   StackTrace:
>          at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdtDescriptor.DescribeCustomType(Object
>   customTypeFactory)

Comment: Alexey - could you provide the full SP_TEST definition? I am interested in seeing how the result set is being created and returned?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent hours trying to identify the issue and it turned out that mapping defined by oracle attributes should have different name than property name.

So I just make all the mapping attributes uppercase and it works now!

```
    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ATTRIBUTE1")]
    public string attribute1 { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ATTRIBUTE2")]
    public string attribute2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: In my case names were different (all lower case in Oracle, Camel case in .NET), but it still did not work. After changing the mapping attributes to upper case everything started working. Thanks!