# Pass Tabled Value parameter using C# for Oracle Procedure

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a procedure which takes a tabled value parameter in my ORACLE DATABASE

```
  TYPE Table1 IS TABLE OF "Owner".Param1.TableName%TYPE;  
  TYPE Table2 IS RECORD (  Param1 NUMBER,  Param2  NUMBER,  Param3   VARCHAR2(20));
  TYPE Table3 IS TABLE OF Table2;
```

And the Procedure is like:

```
      PROCEDURE USP_PROCEDURE_NAME  ( pi_Param_1 Table1, po_Param2 out sys_refcursor ) AS
   output_Table  Table3 := Table3();

    n integer := 0;
    BEGIN
     for r in (select ID, Addl_ID, code from  "Owner"."t_CODE" where ID = pi_Param_1(n))
    loop
      output_Table.extend;
      n := n + 1;
    output_Table(n) := Table2(r.Param1, r.Param2, r.Param3);
   end loop;

    END USP_PROCEDURE_NAME;
```

How can i Call pass the parameter in my c# code.

```
       public DataTable GetFields(DataTable ID)
       {
         DataTable dt_getFields = new DataTable();
         System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter[] oraParam = new System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter[2];
         oraParam[0] = OracleHelper.CreateParam("pi_Param_1", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.??, ParameterDirection.Input, ID);
         oraParam[1] = OracleHelper.CreateParam("po_Param2", System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType.Cursor, ParameterDirection.Output, "0");
         dt_getFields = OracleHelper.ReturnDataTable(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "USP_PROCEDURE_NAME", oraParam)
         return dt_getFields;
        }
```

How to pass the Tabled value parameter as System.Data.OracleClient.OracleType doesnt have anything that suits a DataTable? Is there any other work around for doing so

**Edited:**

I am not able to use OracleDbType as i cannot install Oracle.DataAccess dll in my machine. Is there any alternative for doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass table-type object as input parameter to Stored Procedure in Oracle from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770677/pass-table-type-object-as-input-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-oracle-from-c-s)

Comment: I managed to Add Oracle.DataAccess dll but I am passing the parameter as Array and getting this exception in DB,PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "[" when expecting one of the following:

   ( ) - + case mod new not null <an identifier>