# Issue while invoking an oracle stored procedure from .net with user defined type

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I am trying to invoke an Oracle stored procedure defined in an Orracle package.
The procedure has no input parameters, only an output parameter of user-defined type. Below is the details of the package and UDT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_systemdetail AS OBJECT
(
          sys_id VARCHAR2(8 CHAR),
          sys_name VARCHAR2(6 CHAR),
          sys_desc VARCHAR2(100 CHAR),
          sys_start_date DATE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_systemdetailslist IS TABLE OF obj_systemdetail

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pck_sysDetails IS

    PROCEDURE get_systemdetails(p_system_details OUT NOCOPY tab_systemdetailslist);

END pck_sysDetails;
```

Trying to invoke this from .net as below

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=ptTest;Password=p1_sttest;Data Source=STMP231");
    OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "pck_sysDetails.get_systemdetails";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_system_details", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
        {
            UdtTypeName = "tab_systemdetailslist",
            Size = 100,
            ArrayBindSize = new int[100],
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        });
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Able to connect to db, but getting this error when I execute the code

> ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_SYSTEMDETAILS'

Tried searching a lot but couldn't find anything helpful on how to set this UDT type as output parameter.

Please can any one help me out in this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770677/pass-table-type-object-as-input-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-oracle-from-c-s

Comment: So **what** does happen when you run your code? The more information you provide the more likely you are to get a timely and helpful response. (Although I suspect that @oldprogrammer is on on the right lines.)

Comment: Getting this error when i execute the code - ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_SYSTEMDETAILS' @oldprogrammer thanks for the link..in my case i do not have any input parameter so how can i do this ? I need to map the output parameters ? i mean to say i do not have an input to set like this . oracleParam.Value = entities;

Comment: For future reference please **edit your question** to include clarifications or additional info.

Comment: please can someone help me out here

Comment: Are you trying to get results back from the stored procedure?  Because you are doing an ExecuteNonQuery() which would be used if you don't want results back (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE).  To get results back, maybe look into ExecuteReader.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your output type is not a Varchar2, as you have defined on this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_system_details", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
```

You have `p_system_details` defined as an object of varchar2s and dates, not a single varchar2.  The return type is possibly an `Array` depending on which Oracle data access driver you're using.  For instance, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21935656/1549649) uses a return type of `Array` for their UDT.

If your driver doesn't properly support UDT as the type, I think one option is that you change the return type of your stored procedure to something that the driver supports, for instance something like an Oracle `SYS_REFCURSOR`, defined in .NET as `OracleDbType.RefCursor` can return the same data elements you're looking for.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AOF_JOE_TEST_CURSOR_SP (p_system_details OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS

BEGIN
OPEN p_system_details FOR

SELECT
    'Test1' as sys_id,
    'Test2' as sys_name,
    'Test3' as sys_desc,
    SYSDATE as sys_start_date
FROM DUAL;

END;
```

Then, your parameter is defined in .NET as:

```
OracleParameter cursorParameter = new OracleParameter();
cursorParameter.ParameterName = "p_system_details";
cursorParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cursorParameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
cmd.Parameters.Add(cursorParameter);
```